# Java Class Treating Greater Than as Greater than or Equal To

Tags: java

I have a Java assignment to add a throw/catch to a program. Everything is working, except it's supposed to catch anything less than 0 or greater than 20, it'll catch -1 and below or 21 and above, but it seems to be treating the greater than as a greater than or equal to

Class:

```
public class Rectangle {

private double width;
private double height;

public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
}

public void setWidth(double width) {
    if (width < 0 || width > 20) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Width is not in range");
    }
    this.width = width;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
    if (height < 0 || height > 20) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Height is not in range");
    }
    this.height = height;
}

public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public double calculatePerimeter() {
    return 2 * (width + height);
}

public double calculateArea() {
    return width * height;
}
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class RectangleTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 5);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(25, 5);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(-5, 5);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 5);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 25);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 0);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, -5);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter width and length: ");
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(20,0);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectangle.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectangle.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Area: " + rectangle.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + rectangle.calculatePerimeter());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Why is it treating the 0s and 20s as valid values?

Comment: Because you're treating them as valid values: `width < 0 || width > 20` means that `width` is either less than `0` or greater than `20`.  If you don't want them to be valid, use `<=` and `>=` respectively.

Comment: Not the problem in this example, but in general comparing floating point numbers for equality may be a bit fuzzy because of rounding errors.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code :

```
if(width < 0 || width > 20)
```

means if width = 0 :

```
width < 0 = false 
width > 20 = false
```

`if(false || false )` **=> false**  since it is OR operator.

If you want to check values between 0 and 20 inclusively.

Your condition should be **(width <= 0 ||width >= 20)**

If you want to check values between 0 and 20 exclusively.

Your condition should be **(width < 0 || width > 20)**

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I did (with <=0 || with > 20) so it would be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 20.